# Error in selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to do a select like this -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
DECLARE @Emp varchar(100)
SET @Emp = 'Rick'
SELECT *
FROM [Temporary].[dbo].[Employee_Test]
WHERE [Emp_Name] = @Emp
) AS EMPS
```

**I know that I can fix this** by putting the DECLARE statements before outer select. But, due to some crappy design, I would prefer to be able to use the inner query as is and then count the number of rows in it. How do I do that ?

The error I get is -

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Why not just use: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Temporary].[dbo].[Employee_Test] WHERE [Emp_Name] = 'Rick'` ??

Comment: @JorgeCampos - That is correct, but I am forced to take a complicated way because of someone else's silly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Emp varchar(100)
SET @Emp = 'Rick';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Temporary].[dbo].[Employee_Test]
WHERE [Emp_Name] = @Emp
```

You need to Declare The variable and SET its values before you pass it to the SELECT Statement. You cannot Declare a Variable Inside a Select Statement.

Comment: yes, i know that already. I am gonna bug the guy who forced me to end up in this stupid position.

Answer (score -1):

Should you put a semi-colon after the SET statement?

SET @EMP = 'Rick';